# How to find the URL of downloaded onlineShop-master.zip file from GitHub

Tags: c#, github, zip

I downloaded `Onlineshop-master.zip` written in C# from GitHub long ago. The project was really nice and open source. My idea was to try and follow the steps of the creator. How can I track the original URL of the file, given the fact that I only have the compressed project? The `.zip` is really old so I can't track it using download files and history. I appreciate it if you have the URL of other projects regarding e-commerce.

Answer (score 1):

This is an amazing e-commerce project based on microservices architecture and Docker containers : https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

Good to follow this one as it's contributors are active and it is very well documented.
Regarding that older project, maybe you can try searching for it's class names or other contents, but I'd highly recommend you to check out eShopOnContainers project as it follows the best practices

Comment: It may be [this other one](https://github.com/nouman92/onlineShop)? By the way, I agree with @Rohan Nevrikar answer